# Need help echoing the checked boxes selected by the user

Tags: php, mysql, variables, echo

How to display selected checkbox? I tried but it didnt work

`<input type=checkbox  value="Administrative"<?php echo ($industry_sector1a == 'Administrative' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''); ?>name="industry_sector1"> Administrative`

I use the below for drop down boxes .

```
 <option value="-1"<?php echo ($native_language == '-1' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>----- Please Select -----</option>
                <option value="1"<?php echo ($native_language == '1' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>English - United States</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="foo" />bar
```

Comment: forgot to say using php and mysql

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to use

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Administrative" <?php echo ($industry_sector1a == 'Administrative') ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> name="industry_sector1"> Administrative
```

Comment: <input type="checkbox" value="Administrative" <?php echo ($industry_sector1a == 'Administrative' ? 'checked="checked"' : ''); ?> name="industry_sector1"> Administrative
  This isnt still echoing out anything

Comment: @ope : just mistake of ) , i changed my answer.