# How do i go about echoing the selected check box? tried the below. any ideas

Tags: php, checkbox, echo, selected

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Administrative"  name="industry_sector1" <?php echo ($industry_sector1a == 'Administrative' ? "checked='checked'" : ''); ?>> Administrative
     </td>
                                    <td>
<input type="checkbox" value="Customer Service" name="industry_sector2" <?php echo ($industry_sector2a == 'Customer Service' ? 'checked="checked"' : ''); ?>> Customer Service
```

How do i go about echoing the selected check box? tried the above. any ideas

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129485/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129485/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Administrative"   name="industry_sector1" <?php if(isset($_POST['industry_sector1'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>> Administrative
<input type="checkbox" value="Customer Service" name="industry_sector2" <?php if(isset($_POST['industry_sector2'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>> Customer Service
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['industry_sector1']))
  echo "First checkbox checked";
if (isset($_POST['industry_sector2']))
  echo "Second checkbox checked";
```

Or what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: am trying to give the user a page where they can view previously checked selections. and they should be able to check various options.

Comment: @ope, where are you getting these previous choices from? Database? POST? ..?